# how to stop button getting triggered twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a jquery to use the "enter" key to trigger my button click. it's working fine until the focus is on the button itself. It procs the jQuery for the enter key and also procs the button as if were clicked. I need help on how to handle this kind of situation

JavaScript code

```
$( document ).keypress(function() {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13')
    {
        $('#btnConfirm').trigger('click');
    }

});

$("#btnConfirm").click(function() {
    alert('enter');
});
```

Comment: You added a `click` event handler on the button itself then you added a `keypress` handler on the document that explicitly triggers the button's `click` handler when you hit enter when the button has focus.  Simply stop triggering the `click` from your `keypress` handler.

Comment: there is literally ZERO reasons to have the `$(document).keypress` code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `event.preventDefault()` in the keypress handler. That will prevent the keypress on the button from also triggering a click.

```
$( document ).keypress(function(event) {
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
    if(keycode == '13')
    {
        $('#btnConfirm').trigger('click');
        event.preventDefault();
    }

});
```

You also forgot the `event` parameter to the handler function.

Comment: thanks. I added the event.preventDefault() before but it instead prevented me from firing the click function out of button focus since I put it above the .trigger()

managed to make it work when I put it under the trigger function